# Getting "warning:assignment from incompatible pointer type"

Tags: c

I am getting the error at `fp=fopen("task.txt","r")` please could anybody help me out?
I am trying to open file with `fp(File pointer)`

```
main()
{
    int l=0,pr[100];
    FILE *fp;
    fp=("task.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    printf("No file found");
    char arr[100][20];
    const char *str;int i;
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s",str)!=EOF)
    {
        strcpy(arr[l],str);
        l++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        system(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need the proper `#include`s.

Comment: "_I am getting the error at `fp=fopen("task.txt","r")`_" -- Your code has no such line.

Comment: fp=("task.txt","iiiiia"); mistakenly printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has no such line. Check your code again.

You wrote without fopen

```
fp=("task.txt","r");
```

write this

```
fp=fopen("task.txt","r");
```

you will get it

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
fp=("task.txt","iiiiia");
```

does not contain a call to `fopen()`. This assigns a string literal (`"iiiiia"`, the left one is ignored due to the comma operator separating them) to a `FILE *` which is clearly not sensical.

You should change it to:

```
fp = fopen("task.txt", "rt");
```

to make sense. The second argument to `fopen()` does not define a use for the letter `i` as far as I know and `"rt"` is more in line with the rest of your text.